# Can anyone please explain me how is this happening?

Tags: php, session

I have created a page like account_details.php in which I'm counting the number of times the user visits the page. So for that I have created a file called count_session.php in which the code is like:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['counter'])){
        $_SESSION['counter'] = 0;
    }else{
        $_SESSION['counter'] = $_SESSION['counter'] + 1;
    }
?>
```

I include the above file in account_details.php page in which I want the user to see how many times he has visited and it works fine but I don't understand how does it work? I have checked using the echo message inside the first 'if' condition that is if(!isset) and it seems it does not enter that condition instead it enters the else part but then how come it's getting initialized by 0, but when the user visits the account_details.php page the message pops up like "You have visited this page for 1 times". How come it's calculating 0 + 1 when it's not yet initialized anywhere in the count_session.php file. Can anyone please tell me?

Comment: Read up on [PHP session variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with session variables, as it works the same way for regular variables.

If you write something like `$a = $a + 1` and `$a` is not declared anywhere, PHP considers it as not set, which translates to `0` if cast to int (the same way it translates to `false` if cast to bool, but that's not relevant in this case). The reason why your variable is cast to int, is that PHP feels the need to, because you are trying to perform a mathematical operation on that variable.

To sum up: PHP detects that you want to add up 2 values, does something like `intval($a)` (but internally of course) and adds 1 to that. In addition, if you have notices enabled, this should throw you a notice.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are global to a site (as in hostname) because they are identified by an ID stored in cookies, which are by default sent back to to all URLs under a single domain name. You can restrict that further, but this is the default behavior.